# VB.Net From desginer option missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This morning I opened some legacy code and noticed that I have lost the ability to open the forms in designer mode. When I right click the form files all I see is "View Code," and "View Class Diagram." From what I can tell the resx files and designer files seem correct and intact. I am not receiving any errors in the application as it is runable. Here is the associated files to the form, note this has broken across all forms in the application and is not isolated to this particular one.[image: file associations] 
Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

**Adding the code for the designer file per request**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmQuoteDelivery
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        components.Dispose()
    End If
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(frmQuoteDelivery))
    Dim DataGridViewCellStyle1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle()
    Dim DataGridViewCellStyle2 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle()
    Dim DataGridViewCellStyle3 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle()
    Me.lblQuote1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.imgAES = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    Me.grpControlPanel = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.cmdPrintQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.cmdBuild = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.cmdExit = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.cmdEmailQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.grpQuotes = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.dgvQuotes = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.grpIncludes = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.dgvIncludes = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.grpBuildAQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    Me.cboCustomer = New MTGCComboBox()
    Me.cboMethod = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.lblMethod = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblCustomer = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.QUOTEDELETED = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
    CType(Me.imgAES, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.grpControlPanel.SuspendLayout()
    Me.grpQuotes.SuspendLayout()
    CType(Me.dgvQuotes, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.grpIncludes.SuspendLayout()
    CType(Me.dgvIncludes, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.SuspendLayout()
    CType(Me.dgvBuildAQuote, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'lblQuote1
    '
    Me.lblQuote1.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblQuote1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 14.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblQuote1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(839, 9)
    Me.lblQuote1.Name = "lblQuote1"
    Me.lblQuote1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(171, 23)
    Me.lblQuote1.TabIndex = 77
    Me.lblQuote1.Text = "Quote Delivery"
    Me.lblQuote1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopRight
    '
    'imgAES
    '
    Me.imgAES.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("imgAES.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
    Me.imgAES.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 3)
    Me.imgAES.Name = "imgAES"
    Me.imgAES.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(250, 52)
    Me.imgAES.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.imgAES.TabIndex = 76
    Me.imgAES.TabStop = False
    '
    'grpControlPanel
    '
    Me.grpControlPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdPrintQuote)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdBuild)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdDeleteQuote)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdExit)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdEmailQuote)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Controls.Add(Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.grpControlPanel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(664, 58)
    Me.grpControlPanel.Name = "grpControlPanel"
    Me.grpControlPanel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(346, 168)
    Me.grpControlPanel.TabIndex = 78
    Me.grpControlPanel.TabStop = False
    Me.grpControlPanel.Text = "Control Panel"
    '
    'cmdPrintQuote
    '
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(262, 57)
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.Name = "cmdPrintQuote"
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.TabIndex = 37
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.Text = "Print Quote"
    Me.cmdPrintQuote.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'cmdBuild
    '
    Me.cmdBuild.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cmdBuild.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 14)
    Me.cmdBuild.Name = "cmdBuild"
    Me.cmdBuild.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdBuild.TabIndex = 36
    Me.cmdBuild.Text = "Build"
    Me.cmdBuild.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'cmdDeleteQuote
    '
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(185, 14)
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.Name = "cmdDeleteQuote"
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.TabIndex = 35
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.Text = "Delete Quote"
    Me.cmdDeleteQuote.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'cmdExit
    '
    Me.cmdExit.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cmdExit.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(261, 14)
    Me.cmdExit.Name = "cmdExit"
    Me.cmdExit.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdExit.TabIndex = 34
    Me.cmdExit.Text = "Exit"
    Me.cmdExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'cmdEmailQuote
    '
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(185, 57)
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.Name = "cmdEmailQuote"
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.TabIndex = 32
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.Text = "Email Quote"
    Me.cmdEmailQuote.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'cmdPrintFaxQuote
    '
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(108, 57)
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.Name = "cmdPrintFaxQuote"
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(77, 44)
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.TabIndex = 31
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.Text = "New PDF file"
    Me.cmdPrintFaxQuote.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'grpQuotes
    '
    Me.grpQuotes.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.grpQuotes.Controls.Add(Me.dgvQuotes)
    Me.grpQuotes.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.grpQuotes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 58)
    Me.grpQuotes.Name = "grpQuotes"
    Me.grpQuotes.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(652, 168)
    Me.grpQuotes.TabIndex = 79
    Me.grpQuotes.TabStop = False
    Me.grpQuotes.Text = "Quotes"
    '
    'dgvQuotes
    '
    Me.dgvQuotes.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.dgvQuotes.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.dgvQuotes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 17)
    Me.dgvQuotes.Name = "dgvQuotes"
    DataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.dgvQuotes.RowsDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle1
    Me.dgvQuotes.RowTemplate.Height = 18
    Me.dgvQuotes.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical
    Me.dgvQuotes.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    Me.dgvQuotes.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(636, 145)
    Me.dgvQuotes.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'grpIncludes
    '
    Me.grpIncludes.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.grpIncludes.Controls.Add(Me.dgvIncludes)
    Me.grpIncludes.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.grpIncludes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 234)
    Me.grpIncludes.Name = "grpIncludes"
    Me.grpIncludes.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1004, 168)
    Me.grpIncludes.TabIndex = 80
    Me.grpIncludes.TabStop = False
    Me.grpIncludes.Text = "Includes"
    '
    'dgvIncludes
    '
    Me.dgvIncludes.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.dgvIncludes.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.dgvIncludes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 17)
    Me.dgvIncludes.Name = "dgvIncludes"
    DataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.dgvIncludes.RowsDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle2
    Me.dgvIncludes.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical
    Me.dgvIncludes.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    Me.dgvIncludes.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(987, 144)
    Me.dgvIncludes.TabIndex = 1
    '
    'grpBuildAQuote
    '
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Controls.Add(Me.cboCustomer)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Controls.Add(Me.cboMethod)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Controls.Add(Me.lblMethod)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Controls.Add(Me.lblCustomer)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Controls.Add(Me.dgvBuildAQuote)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 408)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Name = "grpBuildAQuote"
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1001, 271)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.TabIndex = 81
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.TabStop = False
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.Text = "Build A Quote"
    '
    'cboCustomer
    '
    Me.cboCustomer.ArrowBoxColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
    Me.cboCustomer.ArrowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.cboCustomer.BindedControl = CType(resources.GetObject("cboCustomer.BindedControl"), MTGCComboBox.ControlloAssociato)
    Me.cboCustomer.BorderStyle = MTGCComboBox.TipiBordi.FlatXP
    Me.cboCustomer.CharacterCasing = System.Windows.Forms.CharacterCasing.Normal
    Me.cboCustomer.ColumnNum = 2
    Me.cboCustomer.ColumnWidth = "267;40"
    Me.cboCustomer.DisabledArrowBoxColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
    Me.cboCustomer.DisabledArrowColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.cboCustomer.DisabledBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
    Me.cboCustomer.DisabledBorderColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.InactiveBorder
    Me.cboCustomer.DisabledForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText
    Me.cboCustomer.DisplayMember = "Text"
    Me.cboCustomer.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownArrowBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(136, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(169, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(223, Byte), Integer))
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(193, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(210, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(238, Byte), Integer))
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownHeight = 170
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownStyle = MTGCComboBox.CustomDropDownStyle.DropDown
    Me.cboCustomer.DropDownWidth = 327
    Me.cboCustomer.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
    Me.cboCustomer.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cboCustomer.GridLineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray
    Me.cboCustomer.GridLineHorizontal = False
    Me.cboCustomer.GridLineVertical = True
    Me.cboCustomer.HighlightBorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue
    Me.cboCustomer.HighlightBorderOnMouseEvents = True
    Me.cboCustomer.IntegralHeight = False
    Me.cboCustomer.LoadingType = MTGCComboBox.CaricamentoCombo.ComboBoxItem
    Me.cboCustomer.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(82, 16)
    Me.cboCustomer.ManagingFastMouseMoving = True
    Me.cboCustomer.ManagingFastMouseMovingInterval = 30
    Me.cboCustomer.Name = "cboCustomer"
    Me.cboCustomer.NormalBorderColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveBorder
    Me.cboCustomer.SelectedItem = Nothing
    Me.cboCustomer.SelectedValue = Nothing
    Me.cboCustomer.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(356, 22)
    Me.cboCustomer.TabIndex = 7
    '
    'cboMethod
    '
    Me.cboMethod.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    Me.cboMethod.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    Me.cboMethod.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Me.cboMethod.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
    Me.cboMethod.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.cboMethod.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.cboMethod.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Fax", "Email", "Letter", "Phone"})
    Me.cboMethod.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(523, 17)
    Me.cboMethod.Name = "cboMethod"
    Me.cboMethod.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(173, 21)
    Me.cboMethod.TabIndex = 6
    '
    'lblMethod
    '
    Me.lblMethod.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblMethod.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblMethod.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(459, 19)
    Me.lblMethod.Name = "lblMethod"
    Me.lblMethod.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 13)
    Me.lblMethod.TabIndex = 5
    Me.lblMethod.Text = "Method:"
    '
    'lblCustomer
    '
    Me.lblCustomer.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblCustomer.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblCustomer.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 19)
    Me.lblCustomer.Name = "lblCustomer"
    Me.lblCustomer.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 13)
    Me.lblCustomer.TabIndex = 4
    Me.lblCustomer.Text = "Customer:"
    '
    'dgvBuildAQuote
    '
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 44)
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.Name = "dgvBuildAQuote"
    DataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.RowsDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewCellStyle3
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.RowTemplate.Height = 18
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(987, 221)
    Me.dgvBuildAQuote.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'QUOTEDELETED
    '
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.AutoSize = True
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(681, 25)
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.Name = "QUOTEDELETED"
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(118, 17)
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.TabIndex = 82
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.Text = "QUOTEDELETED"
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    Me.QUOTEDELETED.Visible = False
    '
    'frmQuoteDelivery
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(7.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1016, 686)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.QUOTEDELETED)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.grpBuildAQuote)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.grpIncludes)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.grpQuotes)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.grpControlPanel)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblQuote1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.imgAES)
    Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Name = "frmQuoteDelivery"
    Me.Text = "AES - Quote Delivery"
    CType(Me.imgAES, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.grpControlPanel.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.grpQuotes.ResumeLayout(False)
    CType(Me.dgvQuotes, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.grpIncludes.ResumeLayout(False)
    CType(Me.dgvIncludes, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.grpBuildAQuote.PerformLayout()
    CType(Me.dgvBuildAQuote, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents lblQuote1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents imgAES As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
Friend WithEvents grpControlPanel As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents cmdBuild As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents cmdDeleteQuote As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents cmdExit As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents cmdEmailQuote As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents cmdPrintFaxQuote As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents grpQuotes As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents dgvQuotes As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents grpIncludes As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents dgvIncludes As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents grpBuildAQuote As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents dgvBuildAQuote As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents lblCustomer As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents cboMethod As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
Friend WithEvents lblMethod As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents cboCustomer As MTGCComboBox
Friend WithEvents QUOTEDELETED As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
Friend WithEvents cmdPrintQuote As System.Windows.Forms.Button
End Class
```

Comment: Show your code for your `.Designer` file...

Comment: The little lock icon means they are read only / checked in

Comment: @Plutonix indeed it does, but why doesn't it show the `Form` icon for the associated class, that is the issue...Currently its stating its just a class and not a `Form` from what I can see.

Comment: Ahh...didnt notice that part

Comment: I have included the code for the designer file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can happen if you add a class to the form.  The first class in the .vb file needs to be `frmQuoteDelivery` based on that code

Comment: In this case it is. Oddly this code has not been changed in months but all forms in the solution are suddenly having this issue.

Comment: So a month has passed but I was able to figure this out. Oddly enough I had to add a new form to this code today and after adding, the design view tool-tip reappeared on all existing forms. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.